# XUL implicit elements

Tags: menu, element, xul

I've been playing around with buttons in XUL. I discovered that when you put an image on a button it creates an image element inside that button, I know this, because I can style that image with the CSS selector 'button image'.

So, my question is what other implicit elements are there? I want to have a white menu arrow and I can't work out what its called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called "anonymous nodes" and you can see them in [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) for example. If you prefer to inspect them programmatically, [document.getAnonymousNodes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XBL/XBL_1.0_Reference/DOM_Interfaces#getAnonymousNodes) or `document.getAnonymousElementByAttribute()` will give you them ("normal" DOM methods won't, they ignore anonymous nodes). Anonymous nodes are usually created via [XBL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XBL), e.g. the default XBL bindings for buttons can be found in `chrome://global/content/bindings/button.xml` (anonymous nodes are defined in the `<content>` tag). In Firefox 5 this corresponds to the directory `chrome/toolkit/content/global/bindings/` in `omni.jar` - feel free to browse around in this directory (the bindings are assigned in `chrome/toolkit/content/global/xul.css`). When styling anonymous nodes keep in mind that the anonymous nodes will sometimes depend on the operating system (see [<dialog> binding](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/content/widgets/dialog.xml) for an example, note the preprocessor directives choosing code parts based on operating system).

Comment: Thanks heaps Wladimir, this has been so helpful!