# styling a menulist in xul

Tags: css, firefox-addon, xul

Is there a way to style a menulist in XUL?

I'm using this code but the image is appearing inside the dropdownlist and keeping the original style of the arrow.

```
menulist,menupopup{ 
    -moz-appearance: none !important;
    list-style-image: url("chrome://myExt/skin/images/lang.png") !important;
```

}

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are apparently attempting to style isn't the `<menulist>` tag itself but the anonymous `<dropmarker>` tag inside it. This will work:

```
menulist > dropmarker {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border-style: none;
  list-style-image: url("chrome://myExt/skin/images/lang.png");
}
```

For more information on anonymous nodes see [XUL implicit elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525690/xul-implicit-elements/6530773#6530773).

Comment: Thanks alot, menulist,menupopup{ 
  border: none !important;
  -moz-appearance: none !important;
  list-style-image: url("chrome://myExt/skin/images/lang.png") !important;
  background-color:transparent !important;
}
menulist > dropmarker {
  -moz-appearance: none; display:none !important;
  }